# ClickOnce bypass SmartScreenFilter during updates with self-signed certificates

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clickonce

I'm developing my own .NET application for private enterprise use, distributed via ClickOnce over HTTP. One of the struggles I had was SmartScreenFilter (built into Win 8/10) interfering with updates. After every update, it would require administrator privileges (password) to run the updated app for the first time.

Refering to these links - [Link1](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/), [Link2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2005/02/02/how-to-use-makecert-for-trusted-root-certification-authority-and-ssl-certificate-issuance/) - and a bit of trial and error I was able to bypass the SmartScreenFilter.

Essentialy I had to create self-signed trusted certificates to sign my application and then install those certificates on first run. Now there is no getting away from it, but due to self-signed certificates new machines will require administrator privileges (you need to type in the password 3 times in fact). But for enterprise use, where "you" set up machines yourself anyway and install apps, that is okay.

Details are in the answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: create self-signed certificates**

1) We need two of them. The first will be the Certificate Authority and the second will be the actual certificate used for signing the app. Refer to *Link2* for more information. I used the following commands:

(open Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt as administrator)

```
makecert -sv c:\users\Marko\Desktop\CA.pvk -pe -r -n "CN=My Certificate Authority" -sky signature -a sha512 -e 12/31/2099 -cy authority -ss My -sr LocalMachine c:\users\Marko\Desktop\CA.cer

makecert -sv c:\users\Marko\Desktop\cert.pvk -ss My -sr Localmachine -pe -n "CN=MyPublisherName" -eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" -sky signature -a sha512 -e 12/31/2099 -in "My Certificate Authority" -is My -ir LocalMachine c:\users\Marko\Desktop\cert.cer

cert2spc c:\Users\Marko\Desktop\cert.cer c:\Users\Marko\Desktop\cert.spc

pvk2pfx -pvk c:\Users\Marko\Desktop\cert.pvk -pi mypassword -spc c:\users\Marko\Desktop\cert.spc -pfx c:\users\Marko\Desktop\cert.pfx -po mypassword
```

Make sure you use the same `mypassword` for all password prompts. Also modify your folder paths accordignly in those commands.

**Step 2: sign your application assemblies, manifests and .exe**

In Visual Studio, import/add the *cert.pfx* file to your solution. Go to **Project** properties -> **Signing** tab. Tick the `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` checkbox and use the cert.pfx file for signing (`Select from file` button). Then tick `Sign the assembly` checkbox and select the cert.pfx file from the combobox.

Refering to *Link1*, add a Post-Build task to sign the .exe. I choose the Post-Build option, because it was the simplest, also I didn't have any problems with 'signature hash not matching manifest' as described [here](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-revisited/). I used the following command in Visual Studio **Project** properties -> **Build Events** tab -> **Post-build** section:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f "$(ProjectDir)cert.pfx" /p mypassword /v "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)"
```

**Step 3: bypass SmartScreenFilter by importing certificates on first run**

This is the key part. We need to import our certificates to `Local Machine\Root` and `Local Machine\TrustedPublisher` stores. First of all, add *CA.cer* and *cert.cer* files to the solution. Set their *Build Action* to `Content` and *Copy to Output Directory* to `Copy if newer`. Then under **Project** properties -> **Pulish** tab -> **Application files** button -> (tick `Show all files`) set the .cer files to `Publish Status = Data File`.

For the actual importing, I invoked PowerShell in the Window_Loaded() event handler:

```
if (MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun) // I used a custom project setting called 'FirstRun'
{
    try
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process prcs = new System.Diagnostics.Process()) // import certificates
        {
            var dir = (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory :
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "CA.cer");
            var filePath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "cert.cer");

            prcs.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            prcs.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            prcs.StartInfo.Arguments = "Import-Certificate -Filepath '" + filePath + "' -CertStoreLocation cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root;" +
                "Import-Certificate -Filepath '" + filePath + "' -CertStoreLocation cert:\\LocalMachine\\TrustedPublisher;" +
                "Import-Certificate -Filepath '" + filePath2 + "' -CertStoreLocation cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root;" +
                "Import-Certificate -Filepath '" + filePath2 + "' -CertStoreLocation cert:\\LocalMachine\\TrustedPublisher";
            prcs.Start();
            prcs.WaitForExit();
        }

        MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
        MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // if you cancel the UAC dialog for instance
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**End result:**

Under Win 10, standard local user account.
If I go the published URL of my app (http://somedomain.com/MyApp), click the Install button, Setup.exe gets downloaded. Edge will of course warn, that this file is not commonly downloaded = Run anyway.

First password prompt = running the setup.exe (SmartScreenFilter interferes)
Second password prompt = running the installed app (SmartScreenFilter interferes)
Third password prompt = running PowerShell as administartor.

But, if I now publish a new version of my app, then no more password prompts, the application gets updated and ran without SmartScreenFilter interfering :)

**Final note:**

Simply importing CA.cer didn't help, despite cert.cer now being trusted. But importing Both CA.cer and cert.cer did.